# Loading APK into tablet

Tags: android, installation, apk

I have an application that needs to run in Android 2.1 tablet.

1) is there a location I can place the apk where it will automatically be picked by the system installer?

2) How do I bring up the system installer to install the application?  Where do I find this application
   in Android 2.1 device.

3) How do I tell the system installer where the file is located?

4) I have been told You have to activate "Settings" -> "Applications" -> "Unknown source" but I don't see goto settings application, Manage Applications and I don't see this option Unknown Source.  Is this needed and if so where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) is there a location I can place the apk where it will automatically be picked by the system installer?

No.

> 2) How do I bring up the system installer to install the application? Where do I find this application in Android 2.1 device.

There is no end-user "system installer" application that is launchable in the manner you seek. Neither iOS nor Android have the old Windows Mobile concept of "here's a .CAB file, please install it".

> 3) How do I tell the system installer where the file is located?

In code, you call `startActivity()` on an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` that has the proper MIME type and a `Uri` pointing to the file in question.

As a user, you download Astro File Manager or a similar utility from the Android Market and use that.

> Is this needed

Yes.

> and if so where is it?

Right where you are looking. If it is not there, then the device manufacturer -- possibly at the request of the carrier -- has disabled that option. It is possible that it is configured to be always on, so you are welcome to try installing something. However, if this is an AT&T device, for example, they force device manufacturers to disable this option.

All devices that legitimately have the Android Market allow installation of APKs over USB, either using the Android SDK (which you presumably have) or apps like the "Sideload Wonder Machine".

Answer (score 0):

What tablet are you running? Some (like the Nook Color) have very limited settings and can only be used for adb purposes once rooted. Typically what you have to do is either upload your .apk onto the web, download it using the browser and install it from your Downloads section, or, if you have the Android Debugging Bridge installed, do:

```
adb devices
adb install my_app.apk
```

The first line should return:

```
Your_tablet's_serial_number      device
```

and the second line should say success.